# BigQuery public dataset geolite2.ipv4_city_blocks seems to be missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

bigquery-public-data:geolite2.ipv4_city_blocks doesnt seem to exist anymore, I could query other tables in public-data dataset, was geolite2 dataset removed recently?

Error

> Access Denied: Table bigquery-public-data:geolite2.ipv4_city_blocks:
> Permission bigquery.tables.get denied on table
> bigquery-public-data:geolite2.ipv4_city_blocks (or it may not exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the table is not accessible publicly anymore. The table still exists and that is why it is throwing the 'Access denied' error, however it is not accessible publicly.

I am not sure if there are plans for the dataset and table being public again, but I have opened a Public Feature Request for this [1,2] although we cannot provide an ETA for this.
Please, star the issue so you can get mail notifications every time there is an update in the Feature Request [3]. Also, the more stars the Feature Request has, the more likely is to be implemented [4].

Manuel

[1] https://issuetracker.google.com/188375228

[2] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests

[3] https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue

[4] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#what_to_expect_once_youve_opened_an_issue

Comment: The issue link seems to be broken (or at least the id is invalid)

Comment: You are right, the correct Public Issue tracker will be [1]. The engineering team would like to know some further details on how the dataset will be used. Could you please elaborate?

[1] - https://issuetracker.google.com/188375228